# undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

This seems like a simple issue, but I can't for the life of my pinpoint the problem.

**Extracted Source: Show.Html.Erb**

```
  <% if @jobs.any? %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show
    if current_user.role == 4
        @jobs = Job.where(jsender_id: current_user.id).order('created_at DESC')
    else
    end
end
```

My Jobs table is empty which made me first assume that @jobs was being instantiated as 'Nil' since there were no records in the DB. I created a few records but still I am getting the No Method error. Am I missing something here?

**Job.rb for good measure:**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :jsender, :class_name => 'User'
   belongs_to :jrecipient, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only setting `@jobs` when `current_user.role == 4`, so we can say concretely that `current_user.role` is not `4`. It's impossible. If it were, `@jobs` could not be nil, as `.where` cannot return `nil`, it returns an empty array if there are no matched records.

We can't help you further, except to tell you to figure out what the value of `current_user.role` is, and why it isn't what you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it solved my problem. I previously seeded the db with a role table and a before_create :set_role method in my user.rb. It was setting all my roles by default to the value of 1. An oversight from a ancient commit. Thanks again.